# Media change while installing apache2

Tags: ubuntu, apt, software-installation, apache-httpd

I've got a fresh copy of Ubuntu Server 15.04 and installed it via "Easy Install" in VMWare WorkStation 12.

After it installed,i've logged in to my account and tried to install `apache2` with this command:

```
sudo apt-get install apache2
```

and got this message:

> media change: please insert the disc labled
>   Ubuntu-server 15.04 *Vivid Vervet* - Release amd64 (20150422)
>   in the drive '/media/cdrom/' and press enter

I'm sure that the internet connection is okay. But how can I avoid this error and install `apache2`?

I have installation ISOl I can use it as CD, also, I have an internet connection to download, and I can `ping google.com` successfully.

[image: media error on Ubuntu Server]

Comment: Don't post images when text will do. copy and paste the text (commands and output) from your terminal instead. Text is searchable, editable, re-usable and legible in any screen size. It also works for vision impaired users. Images are none of those things.

Comment: well...i am not able to copy them.im not connecting with PUTTY...i am using VMWare on my laptop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to edit your `/etc/apt/sources.list`. Simply open it in your text editor, and comment the lines referring to `cdrom` sources; for example:

```
deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 15.04 _Vivid Vervet_.../ vivid main restricted
```

Save and exit, then run `apt-get update` and `apt-get install apache2` again.

This happened by default since you installed from CD.

Comment: well,thanks,it fixed that error, but now i have this one : http://i.stack.imgur.com/shQni.png

Comment: Did you `sudo apt-get update` first?

Comment: Also can you show me the output of `dpkg --get-selections | grep hold`? You can edit your question and put it there if there's many lines.

Comment: thanks.i did update but for any reason... a restart fixed the problem.

Comment: BTW, remove some `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/*`  files. Because they has been expired.